Spring Boot's @TestPropertySource is not loading properties
I am writing a spring boot integration test where each test would require different properties file. Below is my simple test.
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-redshift.yml")
class RedshiftConverterTests {

    @Value("${application.profileId}")
    private String profileId;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("profile :: "+profileId);
    }
}

And my property file is in src/test/resources. Right now it only has this
application:
  profileId: 45567322

When I run this I get the error that placeholder application.profileId cannot be resolved.
Could not resolve placeholder 'application.profile' in value "${application.profile}"
If I create a application.yml in src/test/resources, and place that property there the test succeeds and it's printed.
If I change the name of the file to something that doesn't exist, inside of @TestPropertySource then I get the error that the file is not found. Which means application-redshift.yml is indeed discovered by Spring Boot, but no properties are loaded.
Why is this happening? Please help

It is working perfectly fine, it simply doesn't support YAML files only properties files. Looking at the naming of the file you can just ditch the @TestPropertySource and add @ActiveProfile("redshift") and now Spring Boot will automatically load it for you.

But, my main application properties are in yml format only. So I must use the same format in test/resources as well.

Why must you use that then? You can combine properties and yaml. But as stated you don't need the @TestPropertySource, specify the profile and it will load the file for you.

replace
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-redshift.yml")
with
@ActiveProfiles({"redshift"})
and you should be fine

When using @TestPropertySource annotation, it is used to provide additional properties for testing purposes, but it does not automatically load a YAML file as a Spring Boot configuration file.

replace
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-redshift.yml")

with
@ActiveProfiles({"redshift"}) 

and you should be fine
When using @TestPropertySource annotation, it is used to provide additional properties for testing purposes, but it does not automatically load a YAML file as a Spring Boot configuration file.

Which is basically a retelling of my answer, butyour logic is wrong. @TestPropertySource simply doesn't support YAML files, out-of-the-box that is. You can make it load YAML files by providing a ProperySourceFactory for it. However there is none provided for that only for property files.
